# Converting ppm file to ASCII art - grayscale calculation

Tags: c, ascii-art

I am writing a program that would convert a ppm file to ASCII art based on the greyness. I have the following code to convert the image:

```
while(fscanf(input, "%d%d%d", &red, &green, &blue)!=EOF){
    int grayscale;
    grayscale = (red + green +blue)/3;
    char c = convert_image_method(grayscale);
    fprintf(output, "%c", c);
}
```

This would work if I processed every pixel in the file one by one. But what if I had to process a larger block of pixels like 2*2 or 3*3? And convert a larger block of pixels into one character with the `convert_image_method`? How should I change the code so hat it would work for both cases? (I also read the width and height of the image and the size of the block of pixels by which I should convert the ppm file)

Comment: Looks like you are treating the data like it is a 1D array, there should be the dimensions of the image at the start of the ppm file. then you should load enough data to process it by block (loading 2 or 3 lines depending on your case)